# Tcl script to correct my output

Tags: for-loop, tcl

I have written a Tcl code which gives me output like below. I am very close to what I need.
Code:

```
for { set row 0 } { $row < 3 } {incr row } {
set row[expr {$row + 1}] [lindex $sub_list $row]
puts "row[expr {$row + 1}] [lindex $sub_list $row]"
set pattern_number [llength [lindex $sub_list $row]]
puts "pattern_number = $pattern number"
set pattern_index [lindex $sub_list $row]

    for {set p 0} { $p < $pattern_number} {incr p} {
      set pattern[expr {$p + 1}] [lindex $pattern_index $p]
      puts "pattern[expr {$p + 1}] [lindex $pattern_index $p]"
    }

}
```

Output of the above code:

```
Row1 A B C D
pattern number = 4
pattern1 A
pattern2 B
pattern3 C
pattern4 D

Row2 P Q R S
pattern number = 4
pattern1 P
pattern2 Q
pattern3 R
pattern4 S

Row3 W X Y 
pattern number = 3
pattern1 W
pattern2 X
pattern3 Y
```

Instead, I want the code to give me output as follows:

```
Row1 A B C D
pattern number = 4
pattern1 A
pattern2 B
pattern3 C
pattern4 D

Row2 P Q R S
pattern number = 4
pattern5 P
pattern6 Q
pattern7 R
pattern8 S

Row3 W X Y 
pattern number = 3
pattern9 W
pattern10 X
pattern11 Y
```

Please suggest what should I do

Comment: ... you didn't provide any code. You need to not reset the variable you're appending to Pattern, but we can't help you if you don't provide any code.

Comment: PherricOxide :  I have added the code for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `foreach`
2. Don't reset the variable

So your code becomes:

```
set rownr 0
set patnr 0
foreach row $sub_list {
    incr rownr
    puts "Row$rownr $row"
    puts "pattern number = [llength $row]"
    foreach pattern $row {
        incr patnr
        puts "pattern$patnr $pattern"
    }
}
```

If you want to process this further, let me know how you need that.
(I assume that you don't really want to generate variable names on the fly.)

Comment: right on the money Johannes, thanks a lot ! Now I am getting what I need. In the above example the 3 is hardcoded. Actually that value comes from a variable. But in your code I am not even specifying it still it is working fine.